# Reloading webbrowser when screen rotates

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I have an application, and in this app I have a simple webbrowser where it opens a login page ( http://portaldopatchwork.klickmembersproject.com.br/login ) , so... after I login in the web page, if I rotate the screen, the webbrowser returns to the login page, I would like to know why? I would like my app could rotate normaly in webbrowser , without returns to login page...

Thanks for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you added xamarin as a tag I am assuming you are doing this in a Xamarin app.

In Xamarin, you can prevent this behavior by putting an attribute on your `Activity`, stating that you will deal with orientation changes yourself. It works like this (the `ConfigurationChanges` part is important):

```
[Activity(Label = "...", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, 
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity {
    // ...
}
```

When you set this flag like above, your activity will not be restarted when the screen size or orientation changes. See [the Xamarin documentation on Preventing Activity Restart](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/handling_rotation/#Preventing_Activity_Restart).

Answer (score 0):

When configuration changes happen the activity is recreated, so if you are opening the login page in a method such as `onCreate` it will navigate to the login page when you rotate your screen as `onCreate` will be called again.

Here is some useful [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)